# What are the ramifications (if any) by using Entity Framework 5 with .NET 4

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

What are the ramifications by using EF 5 with .NET 4?  I see that the latest version for EF in NuGet is 5.0, but I'm running .NET 4 and don't plan to upgrade to 4.5 anytime soon.  It says in NuGet that there are no "dependenices" for EF 5.

I thought I heard somewhere that EF 5 uses .NET 4.5 specific features.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check, but I have heard anecdotally that the enum support requires .NET 4.5

Comment: So you have EF 5 installed and referenced from .NET 4.5 project?

Comment: there are a bunch of performance improvements in EF5 but only when using .net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx):

> Many of the performance improvements made for Entity Framework 5 reside within the core components that ship with .NET 4.5.

And this [Visual Studio magazine article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/05/18/microsoft-releases-another-preview-of-entity-framework-5.aspx) seems to be what Marc was commenting about:

> The Entity Framework RC NuGet package is compatible with the Visual Studio 11 beta, Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.5/4. However, new Entity Framework 5 features such as enums, spatial data types and table-valued functions require .NET 4.5.

I think it's safe to assume these restrictions apply also to the RTM.